# What is the main difference between EventLog.readEvents() and EventLog.writeEvents()?

Tags: android, logging

My First question is:

1) What is the main difference between EventLog.WriteEvent() and EventLog.readEvent()?

My second question is :

2)  I have captured the interaction of users  in android application.Now I need to display this in the form of logs in Logcat?

I have written the captured data as follow:

```
EventLog.writeEvent(LoginEvent,arrayObject);
```

Then I have written a method to readEvent  data as follow:

```
  public void Logindata(){
    try{
        Collection<EventLog.Event> output = new ArrayList<EventLog.Event>();
        EventLog.readEvents(new int[] {LoginTag},output);
        for (EventLog.Event event : output) {
            Object[] object=(Object[]) event.getData();

            Log.i("Logintag",access.toLog(object));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting  "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]"  at  " Object[] object=(Object[]) event.getData();"

But when I execute this it always returns tagCode as -1 .
May I know what is the mistake i am doing in above Code.

Please give Suggestions...

Thank You in Advance:)

Comment: Hmm, how to explain the difference between "read" and "write" without stating the obvious?

Comment: @Muthukrishnan Rajendran  Ya it is working now but it is printing same value 6 times like this        
 D/UserAccessEvent1: {"Timestamp":"1526018142","UserId":"0050N000007H1THQA0","SuccessfulAttempts":0,"FailedAttempts":1,"Attempts":1,"NoOfRevocations":0,"PassCodeChange":0}
 D/UserAccessEvent1: {"Timestamp":"1526018142","UserId":"0050N000007H1THQA0","SuccessfulAttempts":0,"FailedAttempts":1,"Attempts":1,"NoOfRevocations":0,"PassCodeChange":0}
 
 What is the mistake?

Comment: Just remove everything inside for loop and put only **Log.i("Logintag",access.toLog(object));** and check, because after getting the object from loop you are assigning again.

Comment: @Muthukrishnan Rajendran I tried removing everything inside loop except     Object[] object=(Object[]) event.getData();   and Log.i("Logintag",access.toLog(object)); then also it is printing 6 times only?

Comment: Could you tell me what is the datatype of your arrayObject..? and how may times you are calling **writeEvent**..?

Comment: @MuthuKrishnan Rajendran datatype of arrayobject is Object[] . writeEvent is called only once

Comment: @MuthuKrishnan Rajendran It is working fine in one class but another class it is showing     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type.What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EventLog.writeEvent(LoginEvent,arrayObject);
```

writeEvent key is always an int value, you can see the source

```
/**
 * Record an event log message.
 * @param tag The event type tag code
 * @param list A list of values to log
 * @return The number of bytes written
 */
public static native int writeEvent(int tag, Object... list);
```

In that case you don't need to get tag for String `LoginEvent` you can directly use `LoginEvent` as tag code like this,

```
Collection<EventLog.Event> output = new ArrayList<EventLog.Event>();
EventLog.readEvents(new int[] {LoginEvent},output);
```